# create and name NA indicator variables for a large data frame

Tags: r, indicator

Okay, I'm close. Everything works but the last loop for `compound` where I get hung up on a data type issue. Copy and run to your heart's content.

```
x <- c(1:12)
dim(x) <- c(3,4)
x[2,2] <- NA
x[3,3] <- NA
colnames(x) <- c("A","B","C","D")

x

newframe <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = 3))

for (i in 1:3)
  for (j in 1:4)
  { newframe[i,j] <-  (1 -1*(is.na(x[i,j]))) }

newframe <- as.matrix((newframe))

newframe

compound <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = 3))

for (i in 1:3) 
  for (j in 1:4 )
  {  compound[i,j] <- (as.numeric(x[i,j])*(as.numeric(newframe[i,j])))
}

compound
```

I'm trying to create an indicator variable for null instances and use it to create a compound variable that will zero out the original variable when null and flash the indicator.

Comment: Do you really want to test whether the whole column is `NA`? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: OP, regarding your code - try running `NA == NA` and then read `?is.na`

Comment: One step at a time.  You haven't even learned that `x==NA` always returns `NA`. You really should read the R-tutorials before posting basic stuff like this.

Comment: I wrote pseudo code, gentlemen, so criticism of R syntax is inappropriate. I've changed it to is.na above so as not to confuse. The goal is to create the dummy only when an instance of the vector is NA, not the whole thing.

Comment: will post answer in a.m.
    # create data
    x <- c(1:12)
    dim(x) <- c(3,4)
    x[2,2] <- NA
    x[3,3] <- NA
    
    x
    
    # create data frame for indicator var's
    newframe <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 4, nrow = 3))
    
    for (i in 1:3)
      for (j in 1:4)
      { newframe[i,j] <-  (1*(is.na(x[i,j]))) }
    
    newframe
    class(newframe)
    
    # zero out NAs in data
    x[is.na(x)] <- 0
    
    # create data frame for original data and indicator var's
    newdata <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 8, nrow = 3))
    
    newdata <- cbind(x, newframe)
    
    newdata

Comment: @Elliott; Sorry i don't quite understand your last sentence in your question. Does the compound in your code produce the outcome you want. If not, can you add the expected outcome to your question.

Comment: Note: from your comment above; you can create newframe without a loop: newframe <- ifelse(is.na(x) , 1 , 0)

Comment: Since this is a coding site, posting pseudocode is unhelpful. It neither shows what you've tried nor explains what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Carl I cannot agree that posting pseudocode can never be useful, but thank you for your comment. In any event, I'm new here and still learning the culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create indicator var's for missing instances and zero out or impute values for NA instances in original data:

```
# create data
x <- c(1:12)
dim(x) <- c(3,4)
x[2,2] <- NA
x[3,3] <- NA

x

# create data frame for indicator var's
newframe <- 1*(is.na(x))

newframe
class(newframe)

# zero out NAs in data, or alternatively replaced with imputed values
x[is.na(x)] <- 0

# create data frame for original data and indicator var's
newdata <- cbind(x, newframe)

newdata
```

Copy and run.

Comment: I don't understand, this is your solution? Or it is how you have your script?

Comment: @Llopis Yes, this is a toy version that works, which is what people seem to like to see. I answered my own question ("learning by doing"). I am fairly new to R. thanks

Comment: @Elliott; thanks for your solution. Note you do not need to create the data.frames newframe and newdata prior to populating them.

Comment: If this answered the question mark it as so, so other people know it how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
compound <- x
compound[is.na(x)] <- 0
compound
     A B C  D
[1,] 1 4 7 10
[2,] 2 0 8 11
[3,] 3 6 0 12
```